# CTE does not work on azure sql, but works on normal sql server

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm moving my on premises sql server to azure and I'm having problem with one CTE:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[RecUnitLevels]
AS
WITH levels AS (SELECT UnitLevelID, ParentLevelID, CustomerID, Name as LevelName, TimeStamp, CAST('' AS nvarchar(250)) AS Path
FROM  dbo.LogicalUnitLevels
WHERE (ParentLevelID IS NULL)
UNION ALL
SELECT l.UnitLevelID, l.ParentLevelID, l.CustomerID, l.Name as LevelName, l.TimeStamp, CAST((p.Path + '\' + l.Name) AS nvarchar(250)) AS Path
FROM  dbo.LogicalUnitLevels AS l INNER JOIN
levels AS p ON l.ParentLevelID = p.UnitLevelID
)
SELECT UnitLevelID, ParentLevelID, CustomerID, LevelName, TimeStamp, CAST(Path as nvarchar(250)) as Path
FROM  levels AS levels_1
GO
```

the error I get from Azure is:
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "Path" of recursive query "levels".

On my on premises sql (ver 12.0.2000) it works.
If I remove the Path column from the CTE, then the Azure sql accepts the CTE.

Can anybody help me get this CTE to work on Azure Sql?

Thanks,
Nadav

Comment: Tried the exact same query on SSMS and Query Editor for Azure Sql Database and was able to execute it successfully without any change. Created the table with schema CREATE TABLE dbo.LogicalUnitLevels
(
UnitLevelID int, ParentLevelID int, CustomerID INT,[Name] varchar(100), [TimeStamp] datetime
)
Can you pass the definition of table once?

Comment: I've found what the problem was,
the old database had collation Hebrew_CI_AS so all the columns also had this collation,
the new database (azure sql) has collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
the migration process copied the schema including the columns' collation, so now I have tables with hebrew collation in a server with latin collation :(
Once I explicitly specified the colllation on the Path colmn in the view it worked.

Thanks,
Nadav

Comment: Hi @Nadav, we are glad to hear the the problem is resolved and congrations! This could be posted as the answer! I just help you do that, please think about accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.)? This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We are glad to hear that the the problem is resolved and congratulations:

- I've found what the problem was, the old database had collation
  Hebrew_CI_AS so all the columns also had this collation, the new
  database (azure sql) has collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS the
  migration process copied the schema including the columns' collation,
  so now I have tables with hebrew collation in a server with latin
  collation :( Once I explicitly specified the colllation on the Path
  colmn in the view it worked.

I help you post it and this can be beneficial to other community members.