# Adjusting CTE to work on Azure Database for MySql

Tags: mysql, azure, common-table-expression

I have checked this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64151102/cte-does-not-work-on-azure-sql-but-works-on-normal-sql-server) which is similar to my problem. I have a query which ran on previous SQL server, now that whole database is migrated to Azure MySql and the query no longer works:

Query that works on MySQL Server

```
WITH cte_1 AS
(
  SELECT 
    1 AS col1, 
    2 AS col2

),

cte_2 AS
(
  SELECT 
    3 AS col3,
    4 AS col4

)

SELECT 
    normal_table.col0, 
    normal_table.col00,
    cte_1.col1,
    cte_1.col2,
    cte_2.col3,
    cte_2.col4
    
FROM normal_table

LEFT JOIN
    cte_1
        ON normal_table.col0 = cte_1.col1
        
LEFT JOIN
    cte_2
        ON normal_table.col0 = cte_2.col3
```

I get an error:

```
And I get an error stating:
`ou have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'cte_1 AS (`
```

I've tried:

```
        
-- with q as (<query>) select .... from q 
-- becomes 
-- select ... from (<query>) as q       
        
SELECT 
    normal_table.col0, 
    normal_table.col00,
    cte_1.col1,
    cte_1.col2,
    cte_2.col3,
    cte_2.col4
    
FROM normal_table
left join (
SELECT 
    1 AS col1, 
    2 AS col2) as cte_1
    
left join (
SELECT 
    1 AS col3, 
    2 AS col4) as cte_2
```

What structure should I use to adjust the SQL CTEs to work on Azure MySql?

I've also have [read this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and tried adjusting my code but with no success.

Comment: You've tagged SQL Server but you're obviously using MySql

Comment: Regular CTEs like this can be transformed into inline view subqueries.  `with q as (<query>) select .... from q` becomes `select ... from (<query>) as q`.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, Ive updated my question with a more easy to read example, I've mimicked the query that I use with multiple CTEs, is that the right approach I should be using?

Comment: You still need the `ON normal_table.col0 = cte_1.col1` clause in your join.

Comment: Does the updated code work?

Comment: Yes, I've answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
SELECT 
    normal_table.col0, 
    normal_table.col00,
    cte_1.col1,
    cte_1.col2,
    cte_2.col3,
    cte_2.col4

FROM normal_table
left join (
SELECT 
    1 AS col1, 
    2 AS col2) as cte_1
    ON normal_table.col0 = cte_1.col1

left join (
SELECT 
    1 AS col3, 
    2 AS col4) as cte_2
    ON normal_table.col0 = cte_2.col3
```